# Cannot mount anything in a particular local directory using sshfs

Tags: mount, sshfs

I use `sshfs` to mount a remote directory locally. I use Xubuntu 16.04 inside a VirtualBox virtual machine. Yesterday, while everything was mounted, I saved the state of the virtual machine and closed it; I reloaded the saved state this morning. I believe the fact that I use a VM is not really relevant to solving the issue (since it happened once before and I managed to fix it, I just can't remember how), but I'm adding it to explain how the corruption might have happened.

Now nothing will mount on the local directory that was in use, the command will never return. I can have any directory from the remote server mounted in other directories in my local machine, but nothing will mount in the one that I was using yesterday. I have rebooted the Xubuntu machine, and completely powered it off as well, to no avail. I have also restarted the remote server. I can SSH into the remote server as well.

I have made sure nothing is mounted in the problematic directory (`fusermount -u problematic_directory` and `sudo umount -l problematic_directory`).

The following table sums up the situation (`original_dir` is the directory I normally mount; `arbitrary_dir` is any other directory):

```
LOCAL             REMOTE            WORKS
original_dir  <-- original_dir      NO
arbitrary_dir <-- original_dir      YES
original_dir  <-- arbitrary_dir     NO
arbitrary_dir <-- arbitrary_dir     YES
```

This points to something being misconfigured in my local machine, since the remote one doesn't seem to care which of its directories I mount.

There is no information about `original_dir` in `/proc/mounts`, and I have deleted and recreated the (empty) directory, but nothing changed.

I have also removed `sshfs` and `openssh-client` and reinstalled it, no luck either.

The output of running the command in debug mode:

```
$ sshfs -o debug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug,idmap=user me@remoteip:/home/me/project-share /home/me/project-share/
SSHFS version 2.5
FUSE library version: 2.9.4
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-ologlevel=debug> <-2> <me@remoteip> <-s> <sftp>
```

It hangs like that forever.

The output of a successful mount looks like this:

```
$ sshfs -o debug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug,idmap=user me@remoteip:/home/me/project-share /home/me/another-dir/
SSHFS version 2.5
FUSE library version: 2.9.4
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-ologlevel=debug> <-2> <me@remoteip> <-s> <sftp>
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to remoteip [remoteip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
...
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to remoteip ([remoteip]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
Server version: 3
Extension: posix-rename@openssh.com <1>
...
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use other mounting point locally, since I need to have the same path for the local and remote directories and cannot change the path of the remote directory.

**EDIT:** I have found a work-around: mount the remote directory in another directory and then create `original_dir` as a symbolic link:

```
$ mkdir ~/original_dir_mnt_point
$ sshfs -o idmap=user me@REMOTE_IP:~/original_dir ~/original_dir_mnt_point/
$ ln -s ~/original_dir_mnt_point/ ~/original-dir
```

This will only work, however, if the symlink is not created by the time we invoke `sshfs`, so the symlink needs to be recreated for every re-mounting.
I still want to get this properly fixed, though.

Comment: +1 for a detailed question and not at all for using the word "problematic".

Comment: What is the actual output of `fusermount -u problematic_directory` and `sudo umount -l problematic_directory`? You have you tried rebooting the client, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I have tried rebooting both client and server. Both commands don't output anything (well, if I execute `umount` after `fusermount` it complains that nothing is mounted in that directory, because it has just been unmounted).

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I am currently having the same issue.

Comment: @AustinRussell I'm afraid not, I kept using the workaround I mentioned at the end of the post (this was in a computer I no longer own).

Comment: I've run into this as well. I have 2 local mount points where I mount 2 remote directories from the same machine. One day I started having problems mounting one of them (call it A), but the other (call it B) worked fine. I tried another local mount point and A started working. I ran umount and fusermount -u on A but it wasn't mounted. I deleted it and recreated it and it started working again.

The funny part: B stopped working at this point. I've tried the same things with B and it doesn't want to work. Mounting to a different mount point works.

Comment: As a workaround I'm reusing SSH connections:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410252/how-to-reuse-an-ssh-connection

Comment: You could give @JeeHom answer a try. I (un)fortunately cannot reproduce the issue any more.

Answer (score 0):

Shared files or folders need extra drivers "Insert Guest Additions CD image option" is a way of over coming the virtual machine from blocking the file transfers.

Comment: I have been using `sshfs` daily for months with no issue, and I installed guest additions when I created the VM, I'm afraid it's not this.

Answer (score 0):

I having the same issue.
This problem has been bothering me a day, but now  was solved .
It hangs like

```
$ sshfs -p 22 admin@127.0.0.1:/home/admin/fileShare/dart/2.5.0/dart-sdk 
$HOME/dockerSahreFile/dart-sdk -o allow_other -o debug -o sshfs_debug
 SSHFS version 2.10
 FUSE library version: 2.9.7
 nullpath_ok: 0
 nopath: 0
 utime_omit_ok: 0
 executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-oPort=22> <-2> <admin@127.0.0.1> <-s> <sftp>
```

and other output is worked ,like

```
 $ sshfs -p 22 admin@127.0.0.1:/home/admin/fileShare/dart/2.5.0/dart-sdk $HOME/otherDockerSahreFile/dart-sdk -o allow_other -o debug -o sshfs_debug
```

---

Occasionally, I executed it multiple times like:

```
diskutil umount force $HOME/dockerSahreFile/dart-sdk
 or 
 diskutil unmount force $HOME/dockerSahreFile/dart-sdk
```

This problem was solved.